# Strong limit operator of a sequence of operators defined on an incomplete space may be unbounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

In Kreysig Functional Analysis book, following example is given to prove,
Strong limit operator of a sequence of operators defined on an incomplete space may be unbounded.

The space $X$ of all sequence $x=\{x _{j}\}$ in $l^{2}$ with only finitely
many nonzero terms, taken with the metric on $l^{2}$, is not complete. A
sequence of bounded linear operators $T_{n}$ on $X$ is defined by
$$
T_{n}x=(x _{1},2x _{2},3x _{3},\cdots ,nx _{n},x _{n+1},x
_{n+2,\cdots })$$
so that $T_{n}x$ has terms $jx _{j}$ if $j\leqq n$ and $x _{j}$ if $j>n.$%
This sequence $\{T_{n}\}$ converges strongly to the unbounded linear
$$Tx=\{\eta _{k}=kx _{k}\}.$$
how to prove that limit operator is unbounded?? Can you help me in detail,

Comment: If $\delta_n$ is the sequence that is $1$ at the $n$-th position an else $0$ you have that $\|\delta_n\|=1$. What $\|T\delta_n\|$?

Comment: =n. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, why does this imply that $T$ is unbounded?

Comment: \|T(\delta_n)\|=n is not bounded above... is it enough?